# How can I put the two divs on the same line when working with a datatable?

Tags: html, css, datatable

I need help to improve the aesthetics of my project:

I show you the following image of my project so you can see what I mean:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/levMn.png)]

The Excel button is generated using the `class="dt-button"` since I am working with a datatable and I am using the AdminLTE-3.2.0 template.

To get the select and the filter button to be on the same line, use the following CSS properties:

```
  .contenedor {
            /*border: 1px solid black;*/
            /*padding: 2rem 2rem;*/
            /*margin: 1rem;*/  
            text-align: left;
        }
  .contenido {
            display: inline-block;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
            /*padding: 1rem 1rem;*/
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

I need to put the Excel button on the same line as the select and the filter button, or that the select and the filter button are on the same line as the Excel button, either option is valid. The important thing is that they are both on the same line and that the select and filter button are on the left and the Excel button on the right.

Comment: Have you tried `.dt-button { float: right; }` ?

Comment: Ok friend, in this case the button is aligned to the right but it is not on the same line as the select and the button

Comment: Please show me the CSS for `.dt-button`, the select button and other elements. It's hard to tell what causes this from the image. I need some CSS code to give a better solution.